# Kafka Consumer not committing messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams with auto commit strategy.
My root topology is further split into 4 sub-topologies depending upon the type of message received.
Now although my consumer is able to process all messages in 3 topologies, It wait's for the 4th sub-topology message to also finish processing before committing the entire set.
i.e there are 10 messages in the topic
4 messages in sub-topology- 1
3 messages in sub-topology- 2
2 messages in sub-topology- 3
1 messages in sub-topology- 4

Now it wait's for that single last message in sub-topology 4 to finish before committing all the 10 offsets.
Why ?